# How do I pass a class to a child component?

Tags: angular

I have a child component like this:

```
<img [src]="imageToShow" alt="photo">
```

And I want to pass the class through parent to child:

```
<app-image [image]="data.image" class="img w-100 shadow"></app-image>
```

How to do it?

Comment: Please post the full child component - if the child component is ONLY this <img> element or the <img> is the root element of this child component (which would be invalid - an img tag can't have children - you can apply classes directly to the child from the parent as you show. But if the <img> is nested, you can't (easily) pass classes directly to the child. You'd need to use a conditional within the child component and pass that through from the parent and apply classes based on that conditional.

Comment: @TremendusApps In child component only <img> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class are defined "globally" -e.g. in the styles.css or any file you indicate in angular.json (in "styles" array), you can pass as any `@Input` and use [ngClass]

```
//child
@Input() image:string;
@Input() classcss:string;
<img [ngClass]="classcss" [src]="image" alt="photo">

//parent 
<app-image [image]="data.image" classcss="w-100 shadow"></app-image>
```

Another option is use some like

```
//parent
<app-image [image]="data.image" class="child"></app-image>
//parent.css (or styles.css)
.child img{
   width:100%;
   box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

Or simply

```
//parent
<app-image [image]="data.image"></app-image>
//parent.css (or styles.css)
app-image img{  //<--see that use "app-image"
   width:100%;
   box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

You can use also "css variables". So, in child.css

```
img {
   width: var(--width);
   box-shadow: var(--box-shadow)
}
```

In parent.css (or styles.css)

```
app-image {
  --width: 100%;
  --box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
```

but I'm not pretty sure what do you want achieve

Answer (score 0):

-You can import the parent stylesheet into the stylesheet of the child component and just use the class.
-If there is a particular property in that class you want, you can try the inherit value depending on which property it is...maybe might work.

Assuming that is what you mean. If not it would be helpful the see the files.